# Connect 5v 30a relay with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I have previously connected [5V 10A relay switches](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01HXJDBII/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=cd818f9c-142a-4b42-ad2c-f0421857aaf5&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B00C59NOHK&pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_r=MJP2SHRW2PN89Y5J5V18&pf_rd_r=MJP2SHRW2PN89Y5J5V18&pf_rd_p=cd818f9c-142a-4b42-ad2c-f0421857aaf5) to my Arduino.

But for my new project I need to use a [5V 30A relay switch](https://www.amazon.in/xcluma-1-Channel-Module-Optocoupler-Trigger/dp/B072THSX9Q/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=5v%2030a&qid=1564212590&s=industrial&sr=1-1) with my Arduino.

In 10A relay switches, we make connection with Arduino using GND, VCC and IN.

But for 30A switches, there are DC+, DC-, IN.

My question is that, how do I connect my Arduino to the relay using these pins?

Comment: DC+ = VCC. Dc- = gnd. In = in.

Comment: @Majenko Thank you! That answered my question. So, how do I close it?

Comment: You can mark Hobbes' answer as accepted. (Majenko was faster, but he does not seek the merits, obviously)

Comment: Plus I was in bed and using my phone, so it's easier to just drop a comment so the OP has the answer they need then later, if it's still needed, craft a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Amazon page you linked to:

> 1 dc+ : Dc power supply positive pole
>   2 dc- :Dc power supply negative pole (i.e. ground)

Arduino:
VCC: positive DC power supply
GND: ground

[technically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IC_power-supply_pin), VCC = the voltage at the collector of a transistor, these days it's used as shorthand for the positive output pin of an IC.